# Position two images. One top right, the the other bottom left

Tags: image, alignment, positioning

Please can some one help me with ALIGNING one image on the BOTTOM LEFT and the other image on the TOP RIGHT. So i have one basic page... two images and i want them diagonally opposite from each other. Very simple but every thing  i have tried just makes both images align on the right....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution that involves absolute positioning.  It can get tricky to coordinate multiple entities, but it's pretty flexible if you want an exact layout.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 300px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">Top Left</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background-color: blue; width: 100px; height: 100px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">Bottom Right</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UedkS/